# Is there any way to attract the guards?

Tags: payday-2

During many of the games I've recently played where we've attempted to stealth through a bank heist, it has become apparent that the guards seemingly follow rigid paths that change as you kill off each guard.

Is it possible to perform any action (being seen for a certain amount of time, shooting at walls, etc) that will attract a single nearby guard away from his path so I can put a bullet in him?

Comment: I heard that milkshake brings boys to the yard. Perhaps this could be used to your advantage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot directly "lure" the guards (and I think it's a great new skill idea, by the way): just like civilians, they are locked in a pretty basic pathfinding.  Even a guy carrying a grenade-launcher and a giant sport bag, a body armor and some gagball mask popping in a corner won't make them move.

[image: Retarded civilians]

<sup>Source: [**Stealth by Morriperkele** | deviantART](http://morriperkele.deviantart.com/art/Stealth-395052240)</sup>
That being, on some maps, you can use some of the interactive items to attract them

## Bank

You can break cameras without being noticed (my advice is to hit them from their blind spot with your melee attack).  The guards will be notified that something's wrong with one of the cameras and, eventually, one of them will come to check it up.  So you can simply break a camera and hide around it, wait for a guard to pass on, and kill him before he reports the broken camera.

## Framing frame

On day 1, you can lure the guards into the toilet by activating the hand dryer. If the guard is in hearing range, he will go into the toilet to investigate.

Comment: On framing frame day 1, you can lure the guards into the toilet by activating the hand dryer. If the guard is in hearing range, he will go into the toilet to investigate.

Comment: Oh, very interesting !  I'll add that to the answer, thanks !

Comment: Hey @5pike: I tried it yesterday, but *impossible* to activate it.  Any kind of special manipulation or requirement to meet in order to activate the hand dryers ?

Comment: you have to crouch under them - you can hear them blowing.

Comment: Ok...  Yet another glitchy PD2 interaction -_-  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/130539/4797):

- Drills can be used to lure guards. As per [**The Long Guide** by Frankelstner](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=267214370#309672):

  > The noise of drills has a range of 25 meters, causing an enemy within
  >   range to come and investigate during stealth. The range is cut in half
  >   if there is an obstacle between the head of the enemy and the drill,
  >   which usually is the case as enemies spot the drill really fast once
  >   they see it (making the noise redundant). Therefore, in your average
  >   heist, the noise of the drill has an effective range of 12.5 meters.
  >
  > The noise remains the same whether the drill is jammed or not. Having
  >   a silent drill is not always useful, as you actually might want to
  >   lure guards. [...]
  >
  > Drills affected by Silent Drilling aced need to be in the field of
  >   view to be detected.
- In [Firestarter - Day 3](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Firestarter#Day_3), drilling the circuit breaker room's security door at the roof without the [Silent Drilling](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Skills#Silent_Drilling) skill aced, can lure guards.
- In [Election Day - Day 2](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Election_Day#Day_2), the forklifts can be interacted with. It creates noise, and can lure guards.

Comment: I've personally have used the drill method for Firestarter Day 3 and it works like a charm.  If you are doing this on deathwish and want to stealth the run to make it easy, I highly recommend this.

Answer (score -2):

civilians lure people in, for a short amount of distance they do

Comment: Do you mean tied up civilians lure in cops to save them?  Otherwise, I don't think this is true.